# How to fix InversifyJs too much recursion error

Tags: javascript, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs, inversify-binding-decorators

This is my first time I implement [InversifyJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inversify) from scratch. This is a new concept for me to be honest.

I am trying to inject a class `A` in a class `B` and vice-versa. Class `B` In class `A`. But Inversify does not look happy and returns and error `too much recursion`.

Here is an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inversifyjs-stackoverflow-bt9g7s) in CodeSandbox.

I tried to follow the documentation as well in the section of [Circular dependencies](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/circular_dependencies.md), but it looks like I am doing something wrong ? [Maybe ?](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/1206)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for something similar, to solve this issue you need to use factories. See this example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inversifyjs-with-modules-and-factory-stackoverflow-0f70wq). This [topic](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/770) was useful too

```
const myContainer = new Container();
  myContainer.bind<IB>(TYPES.B).to(B).inSingletonScope(); // B is the Child
  myContainer.bind<IA>(TYPES.A).to(A).inSingletonScope(); // A is the Parent
  // The magic below !
  myContainer.bind<FactoryB>(TYPES.BFactory).toFactory<IB>(
      (ctx: interfaces.Context) => (parent: IA) => {
        const b = ctx.container.get<IB>(TYPES.B);
        b.setParent(parent); // setter of parent A in B
        return b;
      }
    );
```